# ListBox.Selected is not working; Run-time error '-2147024809(80070057)

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, hide

Trying to create hide or unhide sheets if selected in a `ListBox`. `ListBox.Selected(c)` is saying couldn't get selected property. It's having the run-time error and if I end instead of debugging, it is hiding or unhiding some sheets.

I tried use `ListIndex` or `ListValue` instead of `ListCount` but it's not going anywhere!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim str As String
Dim Status As String

With ListBox1

Dim C As Long
For C = 1 To ListBox1.ListCount

str = ListBox1.Column(1, ListBox1.ListIndex)


If ListBox1.Selected(C) = True And str = "Visible" Then
Sheets(C).Visible = False

ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(C) = False And str = "Visible" Then
Sheets(C).Visible = True
End If

If ListBox1.Selected(C) = True And str = "Invisible" Then
Sheets(C).Visible = True

ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(C) = False And str = "Invisible" Then
Sheets(C).Visible = False
End If

Next C
Unload Me
End With

End Sub
```

When the ListBox items are selected, on hitting commandbutton it will change the sheets visibility status from hide to unhide or vice versa.[ListBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/442jS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listbox count starts from zero so when you select for example first item on list it never be reached, but for `Sheets` starts from 1, so you need always add 1 to ListBox index to reach it.

EDIT:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim c As Long
    dim intListCount as Long

    intListCount = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

    For c = 0 To intListCount

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(c + 1).Visible = IIf(Me.ListBox1.Selected(c) And Me.ListBox1.List(c, 1) = "Visible", False, True)

    Next c

    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    i = 0
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Me.ListBox1.AddItem
        Me.ListBox1.List(i, 0) = ws.Name
        Me.ListBox1.List(i, 1) = IIf(Not ws.Visible, "Hidden", "Visible")

    i = i + 1
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Please note that error can prompt when you trying to hide all available sheets in workbook.

[image]

Comment: Still not working. It's giving Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range